# Date time formatting from seconds

Tags: c#

I have a variable that contains the number of seconds from a set point in the day.  I need to be able to format that variable into hh:mm:ss - but can't seem to get it to work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string.Format("{0:c}", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
```

Comment: Leaving this here, but the default tostring method uses the same format, so Khan is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The `TimeSpan` class is used for this:

```
var seconds = 125;
var hours = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds).ToString();
```

Output:

> 00:02:05

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a TimeSpan `SetPoint`:

```
var time = (SetPoint + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds)).ToString();
```

Assuming a DateTime `SetPoint`, add this small modification:

```
var time = (SetPoint + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds)).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(double);
```

This will create a time span from the number of seconds. Then use the timespans various ToString methods to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your seconds to a `TimeSpan` and add that to your set time.

```
DateTime mySetDateTime = //your set point;
double mySeconds = //the number of seconds from that set point;
DateTime dateFromSeconds = mySetDateTime + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(mySeconds);
```